# PHP custom routing with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I have read similar questions and answers on stack with a variety of answers but not had a hard definition on what i am trying to achieve.

I have a contact form written in PHP which takes two query parameters which defines which office and what department the form should be submitted to.

```
https:///mylink.com/contact?office=NUMERICAL&department=NUMERICAL
```

Above would be the traditional way to do this, however i would like my link to be in this format.

```
https:///mylink.com/contact/NUMERICAL/NUMERICAL
```

```
location  ~ ^/contact/(.*)$ {
        if ($1 = false) {
            set $1 0;
        }
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/office?setting=$1;
}
```

The above nginx location block works. It only seems to support one parameter however and if i attempt to add another it does not work. Find below the attempt to add another parameter.

```
location  ~ ^/contact/(.*)$/(.*)$ {
        if ($1 = false) {
            set $1 0;
        }
        if ($2 = false) {
            set $2 0;
        }
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/office?office=$1&department=$2;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you for your patience with an NGINX beginner. I suspect this is very easy to achieve since nginx is incredibly powerful but i lack the knowledge on how to implement it and cannot find a clear method in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky guess.

```
location  ~ ^/contact/(.*)/(.*)$

 {
        if ($1 = false) {
            set $1 0;
        }
        if ($2 = false) {
            set $2 0;
        }
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/office?office=$1&department=$2;
}
```

Comment: "Lucky guess" means...what?